apacite and agujournal2019 template: how to truncate the number of authors before the et al.?
I am using the agujournal2019 document class on Overleaf and am having trouble with my citation call-oouts. The default apacite command \cite and \citeA returns Lievens, Reichle, et al., 2017 which should be Lievens, et al., 2017... how can I truncate the two authors before et al., to only one author?
Here are more details, the .bib is:
@article{Lievens2017b,
  title={Joint Sentinel-1 and SMAP data assimilation to improve soil moisture estimates},
  author={Lievens, Hans and Reichle, Rolf H and Liu, Qing and De Lannoy, Gabrielle JM and Dunbar, R Scott and Kim, SB and Das, Narendra N and Cosh, M and Walker, Jeffrey P and Wagner, Wolfgang},
  journal={Geophysical research letters},
  volume={44},
  number={12},
  pages={6145--6153},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}

And in my .tex file, I am using \documentclass[draft]{agujournal2019} where the .cls file agujournal2019.cls is defined as such (here I only show the codes about the bib info):
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

%% In case you want to enter bib entries without using bibtex
\def\references{\thebibliography{}\item[]}
\let\endreferences\endthebibliography

\def\@cite#1#2{{#1\if@tempswa , #2\fi}}

\def\@citex[#1]#2{%
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb}%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\mbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
  %%
  %% This is changed from the default so that lengthy citations can
  %% be broken across lines
       {%\hbox{
\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname%}
}}}{#1}}

\newdimen\bibindent
\setlength\bibindent{1.5em}

\def\refname{References}
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname
        \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}

\def\newblock{\hskip .11em\@plus.33em\@minus.07em}

\RequirePackage{apacite}
%\RequirePackage{natbib}
\let\cite\shortcite %xx So get et al. with three authors the first time.
%\let\citep\shortcite %xx A natbib command.
%\let\citet\shortcite %xx Ditto.
\let\citeA\shortciteA %xx Ditto.

Could you please help me with this issue? Thanks!
=======added information=======
this issue might be due to the fact that I have another paper in my bib file which has same first author and year...as below:
@article{Lievens2017,
  doi = {10.1016/j.rse.2016.11.022},
  //url = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.rse.2016.11.022},
  year = {2017},
  month = feb,
  publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
  volume = {189},
  pages = {194--210},
  author = {H. Lievens and B. Martens and N.E.C. Verhoest and S. Hahn and R.H. Reichle and D.G. Miralles},
  title = {Assimilation of global radar backscatter and radiometer brightness temperature observations to improve soil moisture and land evaporation~estimates},
  journal = {Remote Sensing of Environment}
}

So now the question is, how to print Lievens et al., 2017b instead of Lievens, Reichele et al., 2017 due to the fact that there are two papers from Lievens (as first author) in 2017?

The two entries in question share the same year and the same first author; however, they do not share the full set of authors. Hence, it would violate the APA6 formatting guidelines to generate citation call-outs of the form "Lievens et al. 2017a" and "Lievens et al. 2017b".

thanks for your comment @Mico..let me check some example papers from this journal...
